# Alignment issue for the input type text

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a sample with html and jquery and i am now facing a small alignment issue initially and it is being aligned perfectly when the checkbox is clicked.
Have a look at the snapshots.

Image initially

[image: Image initially]

and image after checkbox is clicked

[image]

Here is my html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signin.css">
<title>First sample</title>
 <script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check1").click(function() {

        $("#passwordRowId").toggle();
        $("#genderRowId").toggle();

    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>


<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center">

    <tr id="checkboxRowId">
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="checkbox"
            id="check1" />check1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="userNameRowId">
        <td>UserName :</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="username"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="passwordRowId">
        <td>Password :</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="password"></td>
    </tr>





    <tr id="genderRowId">
        <td>Select Gender :</td>
        <td><select name="gender">
                <option>male</option>
                <option>female</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center"><input id="signIn" type="button"
            value="Sign In"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the linked css file is

```
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

#passwordRowId {
display: block;
}

#genderRowId {
display: none;
}
```

So now my question is how to align the first layout properly.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer is don't use `display: block` for a table element.

Removing the css shown all works fine

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/67usZ/

Comment: Correct.  If you really want to set the display, it would be `display:table-row`.

Comment: hey but my requirement is to display one table row(password one ) if the checkbox is clicked or display another row(select gender one ).
If i use display-row both are turning invisible or both are turning visible. Could you suggest me something for this

Comment: browsers already set table css default... inspect in a console, and only over ride if you need to

Comment: hide one using `display:none` in css , then toggle will work as you want

Comment: yup that's perfect. Thanks. BTW where the property display: block used?

Comment: suggest doing some CSS research and html research about block level elements, inline elements , and various CSS display properties

Answer (score 1):

Do not use CSS for hiding here, just hide Gender row on page ready.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#genderRowId").toggle();
    $("#check1").click(function() {

        $("#passwordRowId").toggle();
        $("#genderRowId").toggle();

    });
});
```

Comment: toggle default functionality is jst hiding? Actually what the difference between urs and charlietfl answer? Does it effect loading time or so?

Comment: waiting for DOM ready to hide with script makes no sense when CSS will work far sooner

Comment: Why you need it sooner?? It is not a criteria here, It will be hidden exactly when when it is needed to be. Idea is that keeping display:none in CSS and then changing it dynamically in script is NOT a good design decision.